# How to dynamically pip install a .whl file from python code and then use the library

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to pip install a .whl file dynamically (the name of the file will change each time I run it) and import it from the same python script. I tried running it in a different subprocess but I am not able to access the import from within the same file. I think python's importlib might have the answer but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
import subprocess
import sys

@staticmethod
def install_file(lib):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip3", "install", lib]) 

# pip install the whl
install_file(whl_file_name)

# dynamically get the name of the .whl file and import it
whl = __import__(whl_file_name)

whl.do_something()
```

returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'name_of_whl_file'
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Focus on the _problem_, not what you think the solution is. What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: are you sure the subprocess.check_call was successful?

Comment: There is a library I want to use that is stored in a whl file. It can be used by pip installing the whl file. I need to pip install it from a script and then access that library in the same script but I don't know how to

Comment: "I need to pip install it from a script and then access that library in the same script"—again, _why_ do you think you need to do this? Why can't you install it outside of the script? _Again_, focus on the _problem_, not whatever you think the solution is. There's probably a better solution. Please read the XY problem link I posted in my first comment.

Comment: Maybe you could take some inspiration from this code: https://github.com/nvbn/import_from_github_com/blob/7668a0954ed470ab43d11462ca779f24c5e7a7f0/github_com/__init__.py

Comment: Is there maybe confusion between the project name ([example `beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)), the name of the wheel distribution file [`beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/d9/8c507915ff962b9e854b477b203c171074f59cce9465dac9f71c2b57ebd6/beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py2-none-any.whl), and the name of the importable package (`import bs4`)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Solved it this way:

```
def install_file(package: str):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--no-cache-dir", "--no-index", "--find-links", "whlFolder", package], shell=True)
```

This method installs de package from the package name (e.g: 'tensorflow') instead of the filename, searching for the lib file in folder 'whlFolder'.

The `package` parameter must be informed with the package/ library name and the version (optionally). E.g:

```
#Installing the latest available version
install_file('tensorflow')

#Installing a specific version
install_file('tensorflow==2.2.0')
```

Comment: But can you then import the newly installed packages within the same process?

Comment: If you ignore the version parameter when calling pip command I guess it works. But keep in mind that your whl file must be updated.

Comment: I am quite sure this doesn't work, it is not possible to import the newly installed packages. You might want to read the question again.

Comment: I guess you're wrong. First because I said that I had a 'similar problem'. Also, I've tested with tensorflow 2.2.0 and tensorflow 2.3. By ommiting version parameter (e.g. ==2.3) when using pip install, it automatically installs the most recent version. The code I've shown works, and this strategy either. The `package` parameter above might be informed with or without version.

Comment: OK. I am confused... I did a quick test and it indeed works, where I was 100% convinced it could not possibly work. I would change my vote, but I can not unless you edit your answer. -- But to me the question is still not clearly answered, although I must say the question is not clear to begin with.